# jquery.simplemodal > script error on ie8

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I'm facing a javascript error when using `jquery.simplemodal` on internet explorer 8; works fine on chrome, firefox, safari.

error is ***'s.d.wrap' is null or not an object on line 475.***

any idea on how to have it working on internet explorer 8 ?

Relevant code. In the head:

```
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"; type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/system/js/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/system/js/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="{url:/system/js/jquery.ui.mouse.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/system/js/jquery.ui.sortable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/system/js/jquery.simplemodal-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and for a modal window:

```
$("#detail-pane").animate(  { height: gPaneHeight + 'px'     }, 500,
   function() {
      $.modal( "<div id='warning-box' class='warning-box'></div>", 
               { closeHTML:"", 
                 containerCss:{ backgroundColor:"#b8b9b9",
                                height:gPaneHeight, 
                                padding:0, 
                                width:993 },
                 position: [ 108, ($(window).width() / 2) - (993 / 2) ], 
                 overlayClose:true, 
                 onClose:function(dialog) { closePane(); }, 
                 onShow: function(dialog) { // filling in box content 
                                          } 
              }); 
   } 
);
```

thanks in advance,
lionel

Comment: Probably need to check the way you are declaring stuff in your code (add it here if you want people to help). Also, be sure you wiped off cache and the JS used by IE is the most recent version

Comment: In the head section:

`code`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/system/js/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/system/js/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{url:/system/js/jquery.ui.mouse.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/system/js/jquery.ui.sortable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/system/js/jquery.simplemodal-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`code`

Comment: an example of opening a modal:`code`$("#detail-pane").animate( {
height: gPaneHeight + 'px'      
},
500,
function()
{
$.modal( "<div id='warning-box' class='warning-box'></div>", {
 closeHTML:"",
 containerCss:{
  backgroundColor:"#b8b9b9",
  height:gPaneHeight,
  padding:0,
  width:993
 },
 position:[ 108, ($(window).width() / 2) - (993 / 2) ],
 overlayClose:true,
 onClose:function(dialog)
   {
    closePane();
   },
 onShow:  function(dialog)
   {
    // filling in box content
   }
});
} );

`code`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
<script src="{url:/system/js/jquery.ui.mouse.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

be

```
<script src="/system/js/jquery.ui.mouse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

?

Comment: The {url:xxxx} is an instruction from the CMS to manage URLs generated.  After processing by the CMS, it comes with the exact URL.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Simple Modal version 1.4.1
I have upgrade to the latest Simple Modal 1.4.3 and the problem is fixed in IE7 & IE8

Check out http://www.ericmmartin.com/simplemodal-1-4-3-released/

Answer (score 0):

replace to  (d.d.wrap) ? d.d.wrap.focus() : f.focus()